# c++ send empty pointer to function and set it in function without losing scope?

Tags: c++, pointers

how can i set pointer pTT to be set inside function , without losing scope of the pointer beaning set ?

say i have

```
BaseObj* setAction(Holder* pHold) 
{
   pHold = someFrameWorkFactory()->GetHolder();
   BaseObj* pBase = new (pHold);
   return pBase;
}
```

i want later use the pHold pointer in the application , but it remains empty pointer

if i call

```
Holder* m_Holder;
setAction(m_Holder);
m_Holder->getId() //< exception
```

Comment: You can use a pointer to a pointer or a reference to a pointer.

Comment: Does the code, as provided, really build? That allocation you do in the function should not be valid. It looks like a placement-new, but you miss the actual type for the allocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
BaseObj* setAction(Holder* &pHold) 
{
   pHold = someFrameWorkFactory()->GetHolder();
   BaseObj* pBase = new (pHold);
   return pBase;
}
```

if what you want is to modify the pHold variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that unless explicitly asked to, arguments are passed *by value*, i.e. they are copied.

So when you pass your pointer to the function, it's copied and the function modifies only the copy. To modify it you have to pass it by reference:

```
BaseObj* setAction(Holder*& pHold)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use reference :

```
BaseObj* setAction(Holder* &pHold) {
   pHold = someFrameWorkFactory()->GetHolder();
   BaseObj* pBase = new (pHold);
   return pBase;
}
```